# jQuery: HIde prev and next div after a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to hide the prev or next div after clicking on a li element.

This is the script:

```
 jQuery('.menu-ul li').on('click',function(){

   var current_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
    var menu_id = '#' + current_id;

   jQuery(menu_id).next("div").attr("id").hide()
   jQuery(menu_id).prev("div").attr("id").hide();


});
```

The script above works fine, but when I put the function **hide()** I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).next(...).attr(...).hide is not a function
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: `attr` returns either a string or `undefined`. These values do not have `hide` method.

Comment: Read the docs on what these methods return.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but... try removing the `attr("id")`

Answer (score 0):

To ge the previous element use `$(selector).prev()`, and to get the next use `$(selector).next()`. Then use `.hide()` to hide any, or both of them.

Like this:

```
jQuery('.menu-ul li').on('click',function(){

    var current_id = jQuery(this).data('id');

    // We get the element and store it, so we don't get it twice later.
    var element = jQuery('#' + current_id);

   element.prev().hide();
   element.next().hide();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

try following code,

```
jQuery('.menu-ul li').on('click',function(){

   var current_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
    var menu_id = '#' + current_id;

   jQuery(menu_id).next("div").hide()
   jQuery(menu_id).prev("div").hide();


});
```

Comment: This is not a "free code snippets" website, it's a Q&A website; please explain what you have done to fix OP's issue instead of just "try following code".

Comment: You should NEVER keep calling jQuery mindlessly. `jQuery(this)` will give you the object you need and you can cache it. Fixing others code is good, but pushing them in a wrong way is bad.

Comment: @ndugger Thanks buddy for your suggestion. I am new here. Noted them down aill keep that in mind :)

Comment: @abhishrek Thank you too.. :)